# Exit view doesn't stop function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem with stop timer (function) in ionic 3/ angular 5. I want something like this, click back button to previous view  and the timer should stop. Timer will stop when I go to view B and it should again start when I come back to view A.

HTML:

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <button ion-button type="submit" form="myForm" [disabled]="form.invalid" block>Zatwierdź</button>
        <div style="text-align: center; margin: 20px auto; font-size: 16px;">
            Czas do końca sesji:
            <span id="countdown"></span>
        </div>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

result.ts:

```
import { LocationsPage } from './../locations/locations';
import { ModalCountdownPage } from './../modal-countdown/modal-countdown';
import { ModalPage } from './../modal/modal';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular/components/modal/modal-controller';



@IonicPage({
    name: 'page-result',
    segment: 'page-result/',
})
@Component({
    selector: 'page-result',
    templateUrl: 'result.html',
})
export class ResultPage {

    form: FormGroup;

    name: AbstractControl;
    last_name: AbstractControl;
    mail: AbstractControl;
    phone: AbstractControl;
    notes: AbstractControl;

    emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";

    hour: any;
    date: any;
    worker: any[];
    location: any[];
    services: any[];


    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, private fb: FormBuilder, private modal: ModalController, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {

        this.location = this.navParams.get('location') || null;
        this.services = this.navParams.get('services') || null;
        this.worker = this.navParams.get('worker') || null;
        this.date = this.navParams.get('date') || null;
        this.hour = this.navParams.get('hour') || null;


        let removeBr = this.date.replace(/[<]br[^>]*[>]/gi, " ");
        this.date = removeBr;




        this.form = this.fb.group({
            'name': ['', [Validators.required]],
            'last_name': ['', [Validators.required]],
            'mail': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.emailPattern)]],
            'phone': ['', [Validators.required]],
            'notes': ['', [Validators.required]]
        });

        this.name = this.form.get('name');
        this.last_name = this.form.get('last_name');
        this.mail = this.form.get('mail');
        this.phone = this.form.get('phone');
        this.notes = this.form.get('notes');




    }

    async submit() {
        if (this.form.invalid) {
            return false;
        }
    }




    status: boolean;

    countdown(elementName, minutes: number, seconds: number) {

        let element, endTime, mins, msLeft, time;
        let modal = this.modal.create(ModalCountdownPage);
        let nav = this.navCtrl;
        let view = this.viewCtrl.name;
        let status = this.status;
        function endSession() {
            modal.present();
            setTimeout(() => {
                nav.setRoot(LocationsPage);
            }, 500)

        }

        function twoDigits(n) {
            return (n <= 9 ? "0" + n : n);
        }

        function updateTimer() {
            msLeft = endTime - (+new Date);
            if (msLeft < 1000) {
                element.innerHTML = '00:00';
                console.log('status', status);
                console.log('view', view);

                endSession();

            } else {
                time = new Date(msLeft);
                mins = time.getUTCMinutes();
                element.innerHTML = mins + ':' + twoDigits(time.getUTCSeconds());
                setTimeout(updateTimer);



            }
        }
        element = document.getElementById(elementName);
        endTime = (+new Date) + 1000 * (60 * minutes + seconds) + 500;
        if (status === true) {
            updateTimer();
        }


    }





    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.status = true;
        this.countdown('countdown', 0, 5);

    }


    ionViewDidLeave() {
        this.status = false;
        console.log('destroy', this.status);

    }
```

I tried stopping it with changing status(boolean) , when I leave the view, but it's not working.

Comment: Try to use `clearTimeout()` for your `setTimeout()` calls. Here is a tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: Unfortunately it's doesn't work. I tried removeView but modal is still showing when countdown end

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning

```
 let status = this.status;
```

before your function definition. This way the variable *status* will always have the same value within your function from here on. It will either be true or false, whatever value this.status had at the time of assignment.
You will have to use this.status inside your function instead.

```
if (this.status === true) {
  updateTimer();
}
```

But besides that, it should probably be said, that you should think about using setInterval and cancelInterval instead, because it's a cleaner and better soluton for your problem. setTimeout might skip frames, when your CPU is busy, resulting in an inaccurate countdown.

Comment: Thank you for answer. When view load I assign  this.status = true; because timers must start, but  you're right. Function see only true even I exit view, maybe is another way to stop this function

Comment: as i said, just replace (status === true) by (this.status === true) and you should be good to go. maybe you also have to init status with "true", depending on the order of invocation

Comment: I replace status by this.status but not it not working. I init this.status = true in ionViewDidLoad() and change this.status = false when ionViewDidLeave() but timer not stop